# C++ Class Member - Strange Syntax Error

Tags: c++, syntax

I have this class, which should just have a member variable handler m_handle; as you can see. Can you explain how its even possible that i get following error:
Fehler  1   error C2146: Syntaxfehler: missing';' before type 'm_handle'    .
handler is a absolutly normal correctly created class.

```
#ifndef BUTTONMANAGER_HPP
#define BUTTONMANAGER_HPP

#include <SFGUI/SFGUI.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include "handler.hpp"
class buttonmanager 
{
    public:
        void ButtonClick();
        buttonmanager(std::string hover, std::string normal, std::string buttontext, std::string id);
        sfg::Alignment::Ptr GetButton();
        sfg::Button::Ptr GetButtontrue();
    private:
        handler m_handle;
        std::string m_requestparameters;
        sfg::Window::Ptr m_window;
        bool m_needdesk;
        sfg::Spinner::Ptr m_spinner;
        std::string m_hoverS;
        std::string m_normalS;
        sf::Image m_hover;
        sf::Image m_normal;
        sfg::Button::Ptr m_button;
        sfg::Alignment::Ptr m_alignment;
        std::string m_id;
        void OnMouseOver();
        void OnMouseLeave();
        void SendRequest();
//      static void ThreadFunction(sfg::Desktop* pDesk,handler* pHandler,sfg::Window::Ptr pWindow);
};



#endif
```

Handler.hpp

```
#ifndef HANDLER_HPP
#define HANDLER_HPP
#include <SFGUI/SFGUI.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include "buttonmanager.hpp"
class handler 
{
    public:
        handler();
        handler(sfg::Desktop* pDesk);
        sfg::Notebook::Ptr getNotebook();
        sfg::Table::Ptr UpdateBox();
        void scroll(int pType);
        std::string wordWrap( std::string str, size_t width = 55 );
        void filltable(int pPage);
        void SetWordWrap(int pWrap);
        bool m_updaterunning;
        int GetActiveWindows();
        void SetActiveWindows(int pWindows);
        void SetWindow(sfg::Window::Ptr pWindow);
        void SetInfoWindowsActive();
        void SetWindowUpdating(int pCase);
        void SetResponse(std::string pResponse);
        void SetCurrentId(std::string pId);
        void SetTempId(std::string pId);
        void SetId(std::string Id);
        void SendRequest();
        void SendRequest2();
        void SendRequest3();
        void SendRequest4();
        void SendRequest5();
        void SendRequest6();
        void CloseWindow();
        void ButtonClick();

    private:
        sfg::Entry::Ptr m_titleentry;
        sfg::Entry::Ptr m_descriptionentry;
        sfg::Entry::Ptr m_useraddentry;
        sfg::Entry::Ptr m_changetitleentry;
        sfg::Entry::Ptr m_changedescriptionentry;
        int m_windowUpdating;
        sfg::Window::Ptr m_window;
        std::string m_response;
        int m_activeWindows;
        int m_wordwrap;
        std::string m_currentId;
        std::string m_tempId;
        sfg::Desktop* m_desktop;
        sf::Clock m_clock;
        sfg::Notebook::Ptr m_notebook;
        sfg::Box::Ptr m_task_box;
        sfg::Box::Ptr m_project_box;
        sfg::Box::Ptr m_client_box;
        sfg::Box::Ptr m_window_box;
        sfg::Alignment::Ptr alignment;
        std::vector<sfg::Widget> pageone;
        sfg::Table::Ptr m_task_table;
        sfg::Table::Ptr m_project_table;
        sfg::Table::Ptr m_client_table;
        sfg::ScrolledWindow::Ptr m_task_scrolledwindow;
        sfg::ScrolledWindow::Ptr m_project_scrolledwindow;
        sfg::ScrolledWindow::Ptr m_client_scrolledwindow;
        std::string m_username;
        std::string m_password; 
        std::string find(std::string& body, std::string rule);
        std::string replaceAll(std::string str, const std::string from, const std::string to);
        static void handler::RequestThread(int* pUpdating,std::string pSendString);
        static void ThreadFunction(handler* pHandler);

};

#endif // !NOTEBOOK_HPP
```

Comment: You have a cyclic include.

Comment: 95%+ of this code is not necessary for demonstrating your error.

Comment: Sry, but even if i delete the handler include from buttonmanager.hpp error still occurs same way :/

Comment: You don't you have a `#define handler [something]` anywhere, do you?

Comment: And how about the file that include those headers, could you post the `#include`s?

Comment: "even if i delete the handler include from buttonmanager.hpp" --- then you will have `handler` hanging out from nowhere. You have to ask yourself which include is actually needed in each place, and for what purpose.

Comment: Oh, you have to remove the include from `handler`, not `buttonmanager`.

Comment: Buttonmanager need to know about handler and handler needs to know about buttonmanager, thats why both where included and such stuff never made problems.

Comment: @Bruno Ferreira fixed it by your comment, thx for help.